# Codeigniter: Open another page with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Issue seems pretty simple but somehow it is not working for me. There is a user image on index page. Onclick of this image, user profile page should appear.
**index.php**

```
$('#user-navbar').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('gallery/userProfile');?>",
        type: 'GET'
    });
});
```

**gallery Controller**

```
function userProfile()
{
    $this->load->view('userprofile');
}
```

When I click on the user image nothing happens. Right now I am not passing any data to userprofile page. Just want to show that page.

Comment: you won't be able to "show the page" with ajax unless you add the response text to a DOM element, you should read more on how AJAX works

Comment: @koala_dev Thanks for identifying the problem with my approach. Would you like to suggest a solution?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? where do you want the page to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#user-navbar').click(function() {
         var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>gallery/userProfile";  
         $(location).attr('href',url);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

load your view into a variable and pass it to the view , then append it to an existing div

```
public function userProfile()
{
    $my_view = $this->load->view('userprofile','',true);
    echo json_encode($my_view);
}



$('#user-navbar').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>gallery/userProfile",
              dataType:'json',
              type: 'POST'
              success: function(data) {
                   $('#your_div').append(data);
                }  
           });   
      });
```